# Getting a multidimensional array out of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I am getting started with pandas/numpy and I am running into a few snags.

I vectorized an image and stored the data in a pandas column.

```
misc.imresize(misc.imread(path, mode='RGB')
```

The data looks fine, but I just can't get it out in an array format that I need.

```
>>> data['img_vec'].shape 
(19641,)
>>> data['img_vec'][0].shape
(500, 500, 3)
>>> data['img_vec'][0].flatten().shape
(750000,)
>>> data['img_vec'].values.flatten()[0].shape
(500, 500, 3)
```

What I am really looking for is to get the data img_vec to look like this:
(19641, 750000)

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Thanks for the feedback:

```
>>> data['img_vec'][0].reshape((1, 750000), order='C').shape
(1, 750000)
```

However:

```
>>> data['img_vec'].values.reshape((1, 750000), order='C').shape
and
>>> np.reshape(data['img_vec'].values, (1, 750000), order='C').shape
Return "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged"
```

I am assuming it is because it is trying to run it on the data series and not an individual element. How can I run it on the entire data series?

Also:

```
>>> type(data)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
>>> type(data['img_vec'])
pandas.core.series.Series
>>> type(data['img_vec'][0])
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: What is `type(data)`?

Comment: Thanks for response, I added this information to the post.

Comment: you should use reshape((-1, 750000) not reshape((1, 750000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a series of 19,641 numpy arrays of shape `(500, 500, 3)`, and you want a pandas dataframe of shape `(19641, 750000)`. In other words, you want to flatten the arrays, and put their values into columns.

The trick is to cast the flattened arrays into a pandas series. This is how you tell `apply` to put the data into columns, and return a dataframe with 750,000 columns.

```
data['img_vec'].apply(lambda arr: pd.Series(arr.flatten()))
```

If you don't cast into a series, `apply` will return a series of 19,641 arrays of length 750,000.

Comment: I still get shape of (19641,), but the shape of each element is (750000,)

Comment: even this returns the same shape: .apply(lambda x: np.ndarray.flatten(x)[0]).shape

Comment: I think that my data is a bit messed up. type(data['img_vec'][0][0][0]) is ndarray type(data['img_vec'][0][0][0][0]) is uint8 is that right?

Comment: How about `data['img_vec'].apply(lambda arr: pd.Series(arr.flatten()))`? Casting into a pandas series should make `apply` return a dataframe of the size you're after.

Comment: Nice, that did it! Can you point me in a direction that would explain the exact problem? I've been struggling with this for about a day now and not exactly sure what was going on.

Comment: Please see my edited answer and tell me if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

[Numpy's reshape method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) may be what you're looking for.

You may need to tweek the "order" parameter to get the right result (is hard to tell without sample data to reproduce) but the resulting code should look like something along these lines.

```
reshaped_data = np.reshape(data.values, (-1, 750000), order='C')
```

Comment: That definitely looks like something promising. I've updated the post with a bit of more data, can you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: @user2630270 you made a typo when applying this solution, the input shape should be `(-1, 750000)`, not `(1, 750000)`. The `-1` tells numpy to calculate this dimension itself.